# Why does my bullet lack a rigidbody even though it has one?

Tags: unity-game-engine

So I'm making a FPS game and when I try to shoot, it says my bullet lacks a rigidbody. I have  a a rigidbody, so why is it like this?

Here's the bit of code that makes the bullet :

```
Vector3 aimDir = (transform.forward).normalized;
Instantiate(gunData.bulletPrefab, muzzle.position, Quaternion.LookRotation(aimDir, Vector3.up));
Rigidbody bulletRb = gunData.bulletPrefab.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
bulletRb.velocity = aimDir * gunData.bulletSpeed;
```

Comment: Did you check bullet prefab (gunData.bulletPrefab) is attached rigidbody component in unity inspector?

Comment: it has a rigidbody in the heierarchy

Answer (score 1):

You seem to be trying to access the bulletPrefab's rigid body component instead of the newly instantiated object's.

try something like this:

```
var myNewBulletInstance = Instantiate(....
myNewBulletInstance.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
```

Comment: But now it says that my bullet clones lack a rigidbody

Comment: That means your prefab doesn't have a rigidbody

Answer (score 0):

now It works. I also had to create a prefab variant to put the rigidbody on. thanks!